# typo3 disable Menu item

Tags: drop-down-menu, typo3

we use a drop-down menu in typo3 . I would like to deactivate (not clickable) the main menu item and i don't know how to do. For example:

**MainPoint 1** (-> should be not clickable)
- Item 1 (clickable)
- item 2 (clickable)
...
**MainPoint 2** (-> should be not clickable)
- Item 1 (clickable)
- Item 2 (clickable)
...

Can i change that under the point "list - page - edit page (right click) - page type"? I read some tutorials, but i have no idea.

Thanks for advice

Comment: What is the TypoScript code used to generate the menu?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a menu with the typoscript property HMENU, and make some items non-clickable.

If you take a simple 2 level menu typoscript and add the doNotLinkIt = 1 at the appropriate location.

```
lib.subMenu = HMENU
lib.submenu {
   1 = TMENU
   1 {
      wrap = <ul class="first level">|</ul>
      NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
         doNotLinkIt = 1
      }
   }

   2 {
      wrap = <ul class="second level">|</ul>
      NO {
         wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
      }
   }
}
```